# how to implement junit for one interface and multiple implementation class in java

Tags: java, junit

I have one interface(Clause.java) and two implementation class(OrderClause.java and GroupClause.java)
I am unable to create instance of Clause.java class
Please see my ClauseTest class Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:config/applicationContextList.xml")
public class ClauseTest {

    public ClauseTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of getQueryString method, of class Clause.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetQueryString() {
        System.out.println("getQueryString");
        Clause instance = new ClauseImpl();
        String expResult = "";
        String result = instance.getQueryString();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
```

Comment: Hint: everything that doesnt add value to your source code is **waste**. You do not need an empty default constructor; and you do not need all those before/after/up/down methods. Remove them. And then - your question is unclear - as the code you are showing looks correct. So please read "how to ask code isnt working" questions.

Comment: Ok. how to create instance of Clause class

Answer (score 1):

You write that `Clause` is an interface, not class. You cannot instantiate interface directly. You need to create an instance of a class that implements that interface:

```
Clause instance = new OrderClause();
```